# Exception thrown when turning on minify in October CMS

Tags: twig, octobercms

Whenever i set enableAssetMinify to true in cms.php i get the following error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Call to undefined method [registerFilter]").

Also, leaving this to null and turning off app.debug does not work either. I just get the standard error page ( which i just turned on by switching off debug mode after all ).

I can always provide more info if needed, of course. But this error's got me pretty clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with SCSS plugin. I've updated the plugin manually (cloning from Github) and the issue has been resolved. For some reason updating from OctoberCMS backend don't load the last version of plugin.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a bunch!